# how can I print multiple services in this way

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to print both result in php

**In file A**

```
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = array('1000');

$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = array('game');
```

**In File B**

```
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = array('2000');

$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = array('game2');
```

**In file C**

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
  echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

> ERROR E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion -- at echo line

Comment: Can you `print_r($service)`?

Comment: yes same error is occurred using print_r

Comment: Delete first the `echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';` before inserting the `print_r()`

Comment: Array ( [cart] => Array ( [prices] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1000 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2000 ) ) [services] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => game ) [1] => Array ( [0] => game2 ) ) ) ) Array ( [cart] => Array ( [prices] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1000 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2000 ) ) [services] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => game ) [1] => Array ( [0] => game2 ) ) ) )    but i want to print only game2 = 2000 game = 1000

Comment: `echo $service['cart']['services'][$key][0] . ' = ' . $service['cart']['prices'][$key][0] . '<br/>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert services/prices as another array. So use this and it will be ok:

I want to print both result in php

**In file A**

```
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = '1000';

$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = 'game';
```

**In File B**

```
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = '2000';

$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = 'game2';
```

**In file C**

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) {
  echo $service . ' = ' . $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Before $_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = array('games');

Comment: After $_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = 'game';

Comment: Please tell me how can i print the sum of session price array

Comment: array_sum($_SESSION['cart']['prices'])

Comment: and how can i remove a particular value from array  in both price and services please tell